# How to extract readme content based on the keyword in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am currently building a batch script code that will extract the file content on a readme file.

Example Content of the first ReadMe File:

```
Name: Peter Smith
Address: USA
Age: 20
```

Example Content of the second ReadMe File:

```
Name: Matt Uy
Address: USA
Age: 21
```

Now, in my batch script file, I will look for keyword "Name", "Address", and "Age" and produce another text file for the extracted data like sample below:

```
Peter Smith, 20, USA
Matt Uy, 21, USA
```

I have this simple code that finds specific string in the file: How can I output the name of the person next to "Name" and produce another txt file with the name?

```
@echo off
findstr /m "Name" "ReadMe.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo <Enter name here>
)
```

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: You've provided a pretty good example of what you want, could you now try to provide an example of what you've done so far. i.e. your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task I would not use `findstr` but nested `for` loops. In the following script, let us name it `build-list.bat`, there are three loops: the outer-most one resolves the command line arguments which are expected to be the input (ReadMe) file paths/names/patterns; the next loop resolves certain keywords (`Name`, `Age`, `Address`) in the given order; the inner-most `for /F` loop parses the currently iterated input file; in the inner loop body, an `if` query checks for the current keyword (in a case-insensitive manner because of `/I`) and appends the related data to a variable. Here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set KEYWORDS="Name","Age","Address"

for %%F in (%*) do (
    set "LINE="
    for %%K in (%KEYWORDS%) do (
        for /F "usebackq tokens=1,* eol=: delims=:   " %%L in ("%%~F") do (
            if /I "%%L"=="%%~K" (
                set "LINE=!LINE!, %%M"
            )
        )
    )
    if defined LINE echo(!LINE:~2!
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Supposing your input files are called `ReadMe-1.txt`, `ReadMe-2.txt`, etc., and to display the returned data in the console window, run the batch file like this:

```
build-list.bat "ReadMe-*.txt"
```

In case the output data need to be stored into `built-list.txt`, call the batch script like this:

```
build-list.bat "ReadMe-*.txt" > "built-list.txt"
```

(Note that in the option string of the `for /F` loop, the `delims=` part is followed by a colon (`:`), a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character and a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> character in that order.)

Answer (score 1):

It is easier than you think :)

To directly redirect the output of a command to a variable you can use a for-loop:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "Name" "ReadMe.txt"') do set name=%%b
```

You will see that I basically placed your command from above in there. Notice, however, that I took away the `/m` switch!

To use the variable `name` within your if-block, you will need `Delayed Variable Expansion`.

To do so add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your script (usually beneath `@echo off`) and where you need a variable within a closed block of paranthesis change `%varname%` to `!varname!` .

This will print output like

```
Name: Here gets the Name
```

meaning that it will include the leading `Name` you are searching for. <s>To get rid of that as well add another codeline: `set name=!name:~6!` that will delete the first 6 characters (`Name:`).</s>

To include possible other characters and to just get what is after the `:` I modified the loop. It will now get the first and all other tokens (blocks of string) that are separated by `:` and will place the ones after the first into name.

To now get rid of possible leading spaces, you will need another one:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%c in ("!name!") do set name=%%c
```

The `DelayedExpansion` is used here as well!

Total script would look like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
findstr /m "Name" "ReadMe.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "Name" "newfile.txt"') do set name=%%b
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%c in ("!name!") do set name=%%c
echo !name!
)
```

For your other questions, you can use a slightly known search engine named [google](http://google.com). You might want to test that out :)

Comment: thanks for a very detailed answer. Will it accept a lookup with space in between? Also, is it possible to set the first and last characters needed to output? For example "Name        : John Smith         <some text here>". What if we only need the name to be an actual output? and place this in a txt file with header on it? like "Name" "Age" and "Address" as the header?